# Laravel Email verification link using localhost in a production

Tags: php, laravel, email, localhost, email-verification

I've been dealing with an issue for a long time and haven't found a solution.
I'm using Laravel 9 in production, and when the user registers, the verification email is automatically sent, but upon arrival, the following address is seen:

`http://localhost/verify-email/3322/45a667c298ca4ffd2d8f3ea002d9a11c4391ff63?expires=1710354098&signature=1ffba796dc8f5368a064f735fce8888f11b9cfd1ca630444283ab11039a8bc00`

The automatic sending (the first time) is sent with LOCALHOST, but when the user manually clicks the resend button, it sends CORRECTLY.

I'm not using or configured queues. How can I fix this problem?

I've already tried: `php artisan optimize:clear`

This is my .env configuration.

```
APP_NAME=somefun
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:YUiSMZfKLyWPixk3guHIeYS259kX3FD6Yn82osjIIHI=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=http://somefun.com.mx
```

I can't find a way to publish the verification email file (`Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/VerifyEmail.php`), to change de link generation. Because there isn't on vendor publish.

Please help.

Comment: Check the APP_URL in your .env file. It most likely still says localhost

Comment: @aynber
No, it's correct, because as I mentioned, it works when it's done manually; only when it's done automatically, it doesn't work. Besides, I've already verified it.

Comment: Its difficult to debug with that little code. Maybe try clearing the route cache, also? Did you make a search for "localhost"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the notification is sent the first time it does not take it from `.env`, but rather interprets it from the incoming request to solve it I had to do the following:

1. Create a new notification:
   `php artisan make:notification VerifyEmail`
2. Make it extend the original in `Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail`
3. Overwrite the parent function that creates the url `verificationUrl` with a copy of it but including a new line:

It stays like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail as VerifyEmailNotification;

class VerifyEmail extends VerifyEmailNotification
{

    /**
     * Get the verification URL for the given notifiable.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return string
     */
    protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
    {
        if (static::$createUrlCallback) {
            return call_user_func(static::$createUrlCallback, $notifiable);
        }

        URL::forceRootUrl(config('app.url')); //<-------THIS FIXED

        return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
            'verification.verify',
            Carbon::now()->addMinutes(Config::get('auth.verification.expire', 60)),
            [
                'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
                'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

4. In `app\Models\User.php` overwrite the trait function by passing it a new instance of the new notification:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Exception;
use Stripe\Account;
use Stripe\StripeClient;
use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use App\Notifications\VerifyEmail; //<-------Reference to new notification
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasApiTokens,  Notifiable, HasRoles, Billable;

    protected $guarded = [];

    //>>>>Overwrite the trait function by passing it a new instance of the new notification<<<<<<<
    public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
    {
        $this->notify(new VerifyEmail);
    }
}
```

Forcing the url, I don't know if it's a good idea, because I've read that it can do some strange things, but for now I'm not experiencing any inappropriate behavior.